# Installing 2 temporary RV 100 amp outdoor panels

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel

Can you put 2 new rv temporary 100 amp outdoor panels next to each other and what's the most efficient safe wiring for that?

Comment: Please [edit] to add a lot more detail.  This is too little info for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: instead of "can you?" and "what's the best way?" this question seems like a simple "how do I?"

Comment: Who is your electric utility?  Is mounting the panels/pedestals back to back an option?